# Is it possible to type-check against a list of types?

Tags: swift

I know that it's possible to check if one value is an instance of a potential supertype:

```swift
func isInstance<T, U>(_ instance: T, of: U.Type) -> Bool {
    return instance is U
}
```

However, what if you want to check against an entire array? Since you can't have an array of generics, the above approach doesn't really work. What I want to do is something like:

```swift
func isInstance<T>(_ instance: T, of types: [Any.Type]) -> Bool {
    return types.allSatisfy { instance is $0 }
}
```

However, a variable (such as `$0`) isn't allowed as the RHS of an `is` expression. Is this kind of type check possible?

I saw one type check that used `Mirror(reflecting:)` and `superclassMirror` to search the inheritance hierarchy, but that only works for an array of classes, and I need this check to work when the array contains protocols as well.

Comment: Interesting question. Could you share some more details about how you are planning to use this, if it were possible? This looks like an XY problem, where your question is focused on an issue Y you encountered in your solution to some underlying problem X. What’s your problem X?

Comment: I'm trying to keep a collection of type-instance pairs for dependency injection. Most of the time, I can use generics and `as?` to ensure type safety, but now I want to register the same instance under multiple types. I figured I could write a convenience method that takes the types as an array, but then I ran into the problem of type-checking it. To be clear, I'm fine if this returns a boolean rather than causing a compile error (I can put it in an `assert` or `precondition`).

Comment: Do you need to use an array, or can you make a intersection type like `Foo & Bar & Baz` (which is a single type in the end, which you can use with `as?`

Comment: Not currently, due to the way I'm retrieving it. `(Foo & Bar).self == Foo.self` and `(Foo & Bar).self is Foo.Type` both return `false`. There's a reason I'm keeping type-instance pairs rather than just an array of `Any` -- I don't necessarily want to retrieve something that happens to be a certain type, unless it was explicitly registered as such. (If I allowed that, it would be possible to retrieve something by the implementation type rather than the protocol, which would break during testing.)

Comment: Hmmmm interesting. I see what you mean. Have you tried comparing notes with the several existing Swift dependency injection frameworks?

Comment: I haven't seen any others that allow you to register it like this in just one function. IME you have to register it once per type you want to retrieve it as, and perhaps this is why.

Comment: What’s so strange to me is that the type checking functions that you’re reaching for do exist in the swift runtime (checking if one class is a subclass of  another, if an instance conforms to an arbitrary AnyClass, etc.), but it see,s that no public API was ever built for them

Comment: I've been thinking about this again recently, and I had the thought that there could be two overloads of the function -- one which takes `[Any.Type], AnyObject` and doesn't do type-checking, and one which takes `[Protocol], NSObjectProtocol` that does. However, I can't find any information oh how to construct an Objective-C `Protocol` object (or whether it's even possible) in Swift.

Comment: You can pass any Swift `@objc protocol` to where a `Protocol` is expected, from what I remember.

Comment: Yeah, that mostly works. You just can't convert between `Protocol` and `Any.Type`: `P.self as Protocol` works but `(P.self as Any.Type) as? Protocol` doesn't.

Comment: Since `Protocol` kinda blurs the line between objects it's a type. It's an object... that models a type, I thought I'd try `P.self as! AnyObject as! Protocol`. Fails with an interest message: "Could not cast value of type 'Untitled.MyObjectiveCProtocol' (0x1eee94fd8) to 'AnyObject' (0x0): only class metatypes can be converted to AnyObject"

Comment: It is possible to convert an `Any.Type` to a `Protocol`, but the spelling is ridiculously verbose: `P.self as Any.Type as AnyObject as! Protocol`. For some reason, though, the other way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but only for classes and `@objc` protocols, and only if the object conforms to `NSObjectProtocol`. It is not possible in the general case for Swift protocols or value types.

```swift
import ObjectiveC

func isInstance(_ instance: some NSObjectProtocol, of types: [Any.Type]) -> Bool {
    return types.allSatisfy { type in
        if let `class` = type as? AnyClass {
            return instance.isKind(of: `class`)
        } else if let `protocol` = type as AnyObject as? Protocol {
            return instance.conforms(to: `protocol`)
        } else {
            print("Cannot type-check instance against \(type)")
            return false
        }
    }
}
```